# Native MS Office PDF conversion in Terminal Server

Tags: pdf, ms-office

Our application uses native PDF excel conversion to convert MS Word & Excel.

Please see the following url:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834871(v=office.11).aspx

We are having a strange issue when a user connects to a terminal server, and has their local resources (printers) turned on when connecting.

For some reason, with selected profiles, the PDF conversion turns a 1 page document to 16 page document.

Turning of the printers in local resources before connecting to the remote session fixes the issue.

Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to your default printer.  If your default printer changes when the local resources (printers) is enabled and the default printer has a small page size, Word may be re-paginating the document based on the smaller page size.  Explicitly setting the page size or setting the active printer to a known printer may resolve the problem.